# Oracle XMLTYPE extract first node

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I'm having an issue extracting the first node from a specific element of XML within Oracle.

This is the XML:

```
<data type="TestData" version="1">
  <MasterTable Name="TestMaster"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable1">Test</Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable2"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable3"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable4"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable5"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable6"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable7"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable8"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable9"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable10"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable11"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable12"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable13"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable14"/>
  <Fact Name="TestFact1"/>
</data>
```

I am trying to extract the value of the first Name element "TestTable1" and the text for the first Name element "Test".

I have the following queries which are just returning null:

```
select a.xml.extract('//Name[1]') from my_table a; --Attempting to return "TestTable1" from Name attribute 1



select a.xml.extract('//Name[1]/text()') from my_table a; --Attempting to return the text "Test" from Name attribute 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with test as( select xmltype('<data type="TestData" version="1">
  <MasterTable Name="TestMaster"/>
  <Table OtherName="TestTable1">OtherTable</Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable1">Test</Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable2"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable3"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable4"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable5"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable6"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable7"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable8"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable9"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable10"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable11"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable12"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable13"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable14"/>
  <Fact Name="TestFact1"/>
</data>') x from dual)


select t.x.extract('//Table[@Name][1]'),t.x.extract('//Table[1]'),  t.x.extract('//Table[@Name][1]/text()'),t.x.extract('//Table[1]/text()'),t.x.extract('//Table[./text()][1]') from test t;
```

`t.x.extract('//Table[@Name][1]')` returns first 'Table'; with attribute Name 
`t.x.extract('//Table[1]')`  returns first 'Table';
`t.x.extract('//Table[./text()][1]')` return first non-empty table element;

Comment: Thanks for the response! Getting towards what I was wanting to do. t.x.extract('//Table[@Name][1]') returns the whole element e.g. <Table Name="TestTable1">Test</Table>, where I actually wanted to return only TestTable1. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: `@Attribute_name` to access value in attribute `//Table[@Name][1]/@Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLTABLE`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d450e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) as
select xmltype('<data type="TestData" version="1">
  <MasterTable Name="TestMaster"/>
  <Table OtherName="TestTable1">OtherTable</Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable1">Test</Table>
  <Table Name="TestTable2"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable3"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable4"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable5"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable6"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable7"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable8"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable9"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable10"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable11"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable12"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable13"/>
  <Table Name="TestTable14"/>
  <Fact Name="TestFact1"/>
</data>') from dual;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/data/Table[@Name][1]'
         PASSING t.xml
         COLUMNS Name VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@Name'
       ) x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d450e/1/0)**:

```
|       NAME |
|------------|
| TestTable1 |
```